# What is a Moopie?

Tags: japanese-language, phoenix

I’m reading Tezuka’s Phoenix, Yamato book and in it there is a species of shapeshifter called “Moopie” in the English translation. Is this just a nonsense word picked by the translator or does it have some meaning phonetically in Japan (or elsewhere)?
[image: moopie: Tezuka Phoenix]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not all terms need to have a meaning. Moopie are referred to as ムーピー in Japanese, which can be "Moopy" or "Moopie". So it's to say it's a nonsense word chosen by the author.

Comment: Thanks, I am not suggesting it "needs" to have a meaning, just wondering if it does and more specifically if the translation made up a nonsense word or if the original Japanese author, Tezuka, made up the word and the translator converted it phonetically. From your answer it seems you are suggesting the latter, but I think to answer this we would need confirmation that the original text in jaanese included "ムーピー"

Comment: @Drai yes, Tezuka also uses ムーピー in the original Japanese manga. [The official website](https://tezukaosamu.net/jp/manga/398.html) also mentions this name.

Answer (score 0):

If Osamu Tezuka made up the word Moopie or Moopy combining two words, I guess
"Moo" is from movie, motion, move.

And "py" is from copy.

And in terms of Bouba/kiki effect, for me the pronounciation of "moopie" just corresponds to the original appearance of Moopie.